# Inheritance not working

Tags: java, inheritance

Hey im just practicing inheritance and i encountered a problem.  Im getting an error in my car class(sub-class)  that the variables in Vehicle(parent) are not visible.  i didnt do anything to change this and i dont even know how to make it invisible.  Can anyone help me with this.

```
public class Vehicle 
{
    private String make, model, colour;
    private int registrationNumber;

    public Vehicle()
    {
        this.make = "";
        this.model = "";
        this.colour = "";
        this.registrationNumber = 0;


    }


    public Vehicle(String make, String model, String colour,
            int registrationNumber) 
    {
        this.make = make;
        this.model = model;
        this.colour = colour;
        this.registrationNumber = registrationNumber;
    }


    public String getMake() 
    {
        return make;
    }


    public void setMake(String make) 
    {
        this.make = make;
    }


    public String getModel() 
    {
        return model;
    }


    public void setModel(String model) 
    {
        this.model = model;
    }


    public String getColour() 
    {
        return colour;
    }


    public void setColour(String colour) 
    {
        this.colour = colour;
    }


    public int getRegistrationNumber() 
    {
        return registrationNumber;
    }


    public void setRegistrationNumber(int registrationNumber) 
    {
        this.registrationNumber = registrationNumber;
    }



    public String toString() 
    {
        return "Vehicle [make=" + make + ", model=" + model + ", colour="
                + colour + ", registrationNumber=" + registrationNumber + "]";
    }






}

public class Car extends Vehicle
{
private int doors;
private String shape;

public Car()
{
    super();
    this.doors = 0;
    this.shape = "";
}

public Car(String make, String model, String colour, int registrationNumber) 
{
    super(make, model, colour, registrationNumber);
    this.make = make;
    this.model = model;
    this.colour = colour;
    this.registrationNumber = registrationNumber;


}






}
```

The error message:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
The field Vehicle.make is not visible   Car.java    /VehicleApp/src line 19 Java Problem
The field Vehicle.model is not visible  Car.java    /VehicleApp/src line 20 Java Problem
The field Vehicle.colour is not visible Car.java    /VehicleApp/src line 21 Java Problem
The field Vehicle.registrationNumber is not visible Car.java    /VehicleApp/src line 22 Java Problem
```

Comment: Please post the actual error message, not a paraphrasing of the message, and indicate with comments the lines that are causing the error. Don't make us guess at this information. Plus post the child classes. Your question will get answers this time, but in the future incomplete questions may not.

Comment: inheritance works, even stuns! your code doesn't work. edit your post please.

Comment: post your sub class `Car.java`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to and in fact shouldn't set parent fields when you use the super constructor since the `super(...)` constructor call will do this for you.

```
public Car(String make, String model, String colour, int registrationNumber) 
{
    super(make, model, colour, registrationNumber);

    // get rid of these:
    // this.make = make;
    // this.model = model;
    // this.colour = colour;
    // this.registrationNumber = registrationNumber;
}
```

Comment: Dammit.  How did i overlook this.  I am obviously a bit rusty.  Thanks Hovercraft.

Comment: @Pendo: no problem, that's what we're here for.

Comment: Thanks for the "accepting" my answer, but in fact @JonSkeet's answer is the correct one. My answer is just an addendum to his.

Comment: Technically you helped me find the solution.  But if you would like me to accept his.  I will.  And thanks again i appreciate it.

Comment: @Pend: It probably doesn't matter since neither he nor I really need the points.

Comment: Lol true, the both of you are well into the thousands.

Answer (score 7):

The "problem" is that the variables are `private`, so aren't available to the subclass. Presumably you're trying to access them directly within `Car` (it's hard to tell as you didn't include the source).

You *could* make them protected variables - but I would strongly advise you to leave them as `private`, and instead use the properties (the get and set methods) from your subclass. Fields are an implementation detail - you should consider what *API* you expose to subclasses as well as to other code.

For more details on access control in Java, see the [JLS section 6.6](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6). For example:

> Otherwise, if the member or constructor is declared `private`, then access is permitted if and only if it occurs within the body of the top level class (§7.6) that encloses the declaration of the member or constructor.

Comment: I have getters and setters in the parent.  Im obviously missing something because i always use private when initialising variables in the parent and child classes.

Comment: @Pendo: again show the child classes and the actual error messages. Else we won't know what you're missing.

Comment: @Pendo826: You've got getters and setters, yes - but presumably you were trying to access the *variables* directly from `Car`, which you can't do - you have to call the getters/setters. It's very hard to show you what you're doing wrong when you haven't shown us the code that doesn't compile...

Comment: I preferred your other answer. Not that I don't agree with the above

Comment: I edited the Car class constructor.  On the lines this.make = make;
        this.model = model;
        this.colour = colour;
        this.registrationNumber = registrationNumber;
These are showing the error.

Comment: @Pendo: that's the problem, you're directly referencing private parent private fields inside of the child class. Instead use the appropriate `super(...)` constructor to instantiate the fields from the child's constructor. i.e., make `super(make, model, colour, registrationNumber)` the first line of the child constructor that needs this.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels i added the variables to the super() but the errors are still shown :S

Comment: @Pendo: **again** please show the child's code in  your original question that's causing the problem. Otherwise we have to guess at code not seen.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels  The Car class is up now. :)

Comment: I do not agree with this. By making the variables private, that implies that subclasses do not have those fields and that they must declare their own. This also means that vehicle and car have to be two distinct instances.

Comment: @Corey: where do you get that vehicle and care have to be two distinct instances. This recommendation means nothing of the kind. The only difference between this and use of protected is that there's an additional layer of data hiding -- that's all. And in most situations, data hiding is a good thing.

Answer (score 5):

`private` variables won't be visible. They're limited to just the class they're defined in. `protected` variables (and functions) will be visible to subclasses.

Change:

```
private String make, model, colour;
private int registrationNumber;
```

to

```
protected String make, model, colour;
protected int registrationNumber;
```

I recommend against keeping them private because that means that the `Car` does not inherit those variables from `Vehicle`. Forcing a `Car` to call it's own parent's getters and setters is introducing a gap between `Car` and `Vehicle`. It comes off as saying that a `Car` does not have colour, make, model, or a registration number, but it has to go to a separate class (`Vehicle`) and ask the class for it's colour, make, model, and registration number.

Comment: To the original poster: No, don't do this. Jon Skeet has the better answer. You want to limit visibility whenever and wherever possible.

Answer (score 2):

Your `Vehicle` members are *private*. Consequently they're not visible to anyone except the `Vehicle` class. See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Variables:

`private` means the variable is only visible within that class. For example

```
Class foo {
    private Object a; //a can only be accessed within foo.
}
```

`protected` means for that class and classes that intherit. For example

```
Class foo {
    protected Object a;
}

Class bar extends foo {
    public bar () {
        a = someVariable;
    }
}
```

`public` means all classes that can access a object of that class. For example

```
Class foo{
    public Object a;
}

Class bar{
    public bar(){
        foo foo = new foo();
        foo.a = someVariable;
    }
}
```